# How to change letters from lower case to upper case with markdown syntax?

Tags: markdown

How do I turn lower case letter to upper case by using Markdown syntax? For example, the user enters "test" in the editor and I want it to be converted to either "Test", or "tEst", for example Thank you

Comment: Markdown doesn't support it.  You'd have to write some kind of "shortcode" (supported by some static site generators) or similar mechanism/macro in order to achieve what you're describing... but you haven't described much about what else you're using.

Comment: Your question isn't very specific. You could post-process your output or using something like https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Markdown doesn't provide a mechanism for case switching.

Complete syntax:
https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax